# Python: Optimization with Exponential Objective Function

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am working on assignment problems. So far, I have been using `Gurobi` via gurobipy. In my current problem, I have an objective function with an exponential term. In gurobipy this would be

```
m.setObjective(ratings.prod(assign) ** 0.5, sense=GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

but `**` (or `pow()`) is not supported in Gurobi. What are other options (with other tools than Gurobi) or workarounds?

Below is a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import random

def solve():
    m = gp.Model()
    assign = m.addVars(permutations, vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="assign")
    m.addConstrs((assign.sum(i, "*") == 1 for i in individuals))
    capacity = {
      'P1':40, 'P2':30, 'P3':30
    }
    m.addConstrs(
        (assign.sum("*", p) <= capacity[p] for p in groups),
        name="limit"
    )
    
    # objective function
    m.setObjective(ratings.prod(assign) ** 0.5, sense=GRB.MAXIMIZE)

    m.optimize()
    return m, assign

def get_results(assign):
    # create df with placeholder
    results = pd.DataFrame(-1, index=individuals, columns=groups)
    
    # fill in the results
    for (i, j), x_ij in assign.items():
        results.loc[i, j] = int(x_ij.X)

    return results
  
# minimal example
outcomes = []
for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.uniform(0, 1)  
    outcomes.append(x)

data = {'P1': outcomes, 
        'P2': random.sample(outcomes, len(outcomes)),
        'P3': random.sample(outcomes, len(outcomes))}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

individuals = list(df.index)
groups = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']

# prepare
permutations, ratings = gp.multidict({
       (i, j): df.loc[i, j]
       for i in individuals
       for j in groups
   })  
   
# run   
m, assign = solve()    
results = get_results(assign)    
printresults)
```

Comment: The gurobipy landing page says it is for use with MIP and quadratic formulations, which would exclude the root you are trying to do...  That said, and I'm not familiar with gurobi syntax, so maybe this is off-base, but is your objective function with the `.prod` operation the square root of the sum product of the values and the binary variables?  If so, you can drop the exponent as maximizing the basic sum product will get you the same variable values and then just take the square root of the objective value after-the-fact.... No?

Comment: The solutions does not have to be with Gurobi. I am happy to switch tools. To the other question: I will try it.

Comment: If you are comfortable with Gurobi (and have the expensive license or academic version), there might not be reason to switch.  Realize maximizing `f(x)` where x is some combination of variables and maximizing `sqrt(f(x))` will give the same values of `x` within the constraints, with obviously differing objective values...  But one only has to take the sqrt of `f(x)` after the objective is computed to arrive at the same place.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. How would this look like in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, just take the sqrt after the fact...  Unless I'm missing something fundamental in the gurobi syntax.  Instead of using this:

```
m.setObjective(ratings.prod(assign) ** 0.5, sense=GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

use this:

```
m.setObjective(ratings.prod(assign), sense=GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

Then solve the model with this objective, which will get the same values for `assign` and then *after the solve*, get the value of the objective out of the model (not sure how to do this in gurobi syntax, so this is psuedocode:

```
obj_value = m.get_objective_value_somehow_in_gurobi_syntax  ??
```

and then just take the sqrt of that...

```
real_obj_value = math.sqrt(obj_value)
```

the values of the variables that maximize `obj_value` and `real_obj_value` are the same.

##### Edit:  working with terms with sqrt

New plan...  per comments you actually intend to use sqrt of individual terms in the sum-product, so the above strategy will not work.

However, because your decision variables are binary, you can implement a work-around....

Make a separate dictionary of "corrected values" that is just the sqrt of the individual values.  (I'm assuming you still want the original values for use in some constraints, etc. so retain and use those as well)  They are both indexed identically, so use the originals in the constraints and the corrected in the objective.

So in psuedocode something like:

```
corr_values = {k:v**0.5 for k, v in values_dict}
```

then just use the *corrected values* in your objective function, which is mathematically fine because you are only multiplying by 1 or 0:

```
1 * v**0.5 == (1 * v)**0.5
```

and you will get the outcome you desire and the low values will be weighted appropriately

Comment: Thanks! The "** 0.5" has the effect that a change in lower outcome values has a greater influence on the objective than a change in larger outcome values. I wouldn't think both lead to the same assignment. This is where I am wrong maybe.

Comment: You are taking the square root of the aggregate total, no?  If so it doesn't matter.  If you were "rooting" the individual terms, then summing I would agree with you.

Comment: I unterstand. My intention was to root the individual terms - but I could also do this outside of the m.setObjective() I guess, just before for every single value, no?

Comment: See my edit above, I think it hits the mark.  If you try to implement the root operation on variables, you'll be back where you started